# Using custom jquery plugin in Backbone View's events hash

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, backbone.js

I have extended jquery to have a `returnPress` event handler like this:

```
jQuery.fn.returnPress = function(x) {
    return this.each(function() {
        jQuery(this).keypress(function(e) {
            if((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
                x();
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I can use the above like this in my views:

```
this.$('#inputId').returnPress(function(){
    doSomething();
});
```

However i want to use it inside the Backbone View's `event` hash like this:

```
events : { "returnPress #inputId" : "doSomething" }
```

Is this possible? What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

Events hash is taking the events which you can bind with on, so the events hash is doig the same as:

```
this.$('#inputId').on ('returnPress', function(){
  doSomething();
});
```

Comment: So is there a way to make it work with `events : { "returnPress #inputId " : "doSomething" }` ?

Comment: You can make it work with a little bit different perspective of your jQuery extension ... look @ http://jsfiddle.net/sHAgU/